# LINQ Query IList<string> to JSon Format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, linq, ilist

I have a Class that return a List of Users

```
public IList<RegisterUsers> GetUsers()
{
    var query = (from up in _context.UserProfile
                     join um in _context.Membership on up.UserID equals um.UserID
                     select new RegisterUsers { ID = ua.UserID, FirstName = ua.FirstName, LastName = ua.LastName, LastLogIn = up.LastLogIn, Status = up.Status });

    return query.ToList();
}
```

I call this class by doing the following on my Action

```
var UserRepository = new UserRepository();
var AllUsers = UserRepository.GetUsers();


var result = from c in AllUsers
                select new List<string> { c.ID.ToString(), c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.LastLogIn,c.Status };


return Json(new { sEcho = param.sEcho,
                  iTotalRecords = result.Count(),
                  iTotalDisplayRecords = result.Count(),
                  aaData = result
                },
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The above code works fine and it return JSON data. But I'm trying o figure out why I get an error if I just attach the AllUsers directly to the aaData variable. Please see below.

```
var UserRepository = new UserRepository();
var AllUsers = UserRepository.GetUsers();

return Json(new { sEcho = param.sEcho,
                  iTotalRecords = AllUsers.Count(),
                  iTotalDisplayRecords = AllUsers.Count(),
                  aaData = AllUsers
                },
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: What is the error text?

Comment: Perhaps because `AllUsers` is a List of Registered users, whereas `aaData` is looking for **???**

Comment: The aaData is expecting a two-dimensional matrix containing the cells. Below is a URL of what Im trying to accomplish.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Comment: Ever get it figured out?

Comment: Yes, I got it to work. I'll post the code within the next few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Return a List by doing the following

```
var AllUsers = UserRepository.GetUsers().Select(p => new List<string> { p.UserID.ToString(), p.FirstName, p.LastName }).ToList();
```

Basically the above code just eliminates the following line of code

```
var result = from c in AllUsers
            select new List<string> { c.ID.ToString(), c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.LastLogIn,c.Status };
```

Hopefully I was able to answer your question.